# PyAutoGUI WindowsError: [Error 5]

Tags: python

I am working with PyAutoGUI in Python 2.7 using PyCharm and am getting a permissions error.  Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


# Open the browser.

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()


# Click on the address bar.

pyautogui.click(x=150,y=50)


# Fill in the URL.

pyautogui.typewrite('yahoo.com')
```

The windows is opening and maximizing just fine and the mouse is moving and clicking (I tried the code on my IDE and it moved and clicked the top toolbar), but alas, nothing is being typed.  How do I fix the permissions so that I can click and type?

NOTE:  The script DOES work when run from the command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be solved in 0.9.34, so you just need to update PyAutoGUI by running `pip install -U pyautogui`.